# Permission problems installing with sudo between 14.04 and 16.04

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, permissions, sudo, umask

I have run into many permissions problems installing packages in 16.04.  I install them using `sudo`, but then normal users cannot read the files in the package.

So I ran a simple test:  I created a directory using `sudo` in 14.04, and looked at the permissions:

```
sudo mkdir test_14_04
ls -ld test_14_04/ 
#returns: drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jan  3 05:57 test_14_04/
```

Then I did the same thing in 16.04, but instead I get:

```
#returns: drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4096 Jan  3 06:00 test_16_04/
```

As you can see, the default permission is world read in 14.04 but not in 16.04. So this may be the problem with the `sudo`-installed package permissions.

How can I fix this?

PS:
My 16.04 Ubuntu version is:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

and my 14.04 version is:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About your question:

Execute `sudo visudo` and add the following lines:

```
`Defaults umask=0022`
`Defaults umask_override`
```

umask_override [(see the sudoers manpage)](https://linux.die.net/man/5/sudoers):

> If set, sudo will set the umask as specified by sudoers without
>   modification. This makes it possible to specify a more permissive
>   umask in sudoers than the user's own umask and matches historical
>   behavior. If umask_override is not set, sudo will set the umask to be
>   the union of the user's umask and what is specified in sudoers. This
>   flag is off by default. If set, sudo will run the command in a
>   pseudo-pty even if no I/O logging is being gone. A malicious program
>   run under sudo could conceivably fork a background process that
>   retains to the user's terminal device after the main program has
>   finished executing. Use of this option will make that impossible. This
>   flag is off by default.

Hope this helps, good luck!

Answer (score 6):

The problem you are facing seems to be with the default value of `root` `umask`

The permissions which were created in the 14.04 version, are equal to `umask` of `0022` which should the be default `root` value from `umask`

```
# umask
0022
```

It seems like your default `umask` in the `16.04` is `0027`, which can be checked by running in the `root` prompt:

```
umask
```

in order to change the default behavior, you'll need to check `root` start scripts (`profile`, `login`, etc) and find where this value was set, and to change it to be:

```
umask 0022
```

Instead of:

```
umask 0027
```

More info can be found in [understanding linux umask value usage](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/understanding-linux-unix-umask-value-usage.html)

---

Example:

```
root@ubuntu:~# umask
0022
root@ubuntu:~# mkdir /tmp/z123
root@ubuntu:~# ll -ld /tmp/z123
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jan  3 14:51 /tmp/z123/
root@ubuntu:~# umask 0027
root@ubuntu:~# umask
0027
root@ubuntu:~# mkdir /tmp/a123
root@ubuntu:~# ll -ld /tmp/a123
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4096 Jan  3 14:54 /tmp/a123/
```

Comment: This doesn't work for sudo.  I added umask 0022 to /root/.bashrc, and this works for root, but it didn't affect the default file permissions for sudo.